# how to get a float from a string?

Tags: java, string, floating-point

Is there any **Java method** that equivalents to **[php floatval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)**?

If not, how can I get **float value** of a **string** in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using **regex**:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("some string and then a number 123.456789 and continue");

if ( m.find() ) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); // 123.456789
}
```

Comment: Could you provide me an example with **your code** that returns **123.456789** from the string: "**some string 123.456789 and continue**". Thanks.

Comment: Use `java.util.Scanner`

 http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: So, that was not **Exactly** the same as **floatval ;)**

Answer (score 7):

```
float f = Float.parseFloat("25");
String s = Float.toString(25.0f);
```

`System.out.printf("%f", Float.parseFloat("1.0E7"));` outputs `10000000.000000`

See http://ideone.com/3o6dO

updated from natasha answer

use regex

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("some string and then a number 123.456789 and continue");
    while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. What about this string: "122.34343The". And I want the number part: 122.34343

Comment: it will through a exception `NumberFormatException: For input string: "122.34343The"` and  check this link too http://ideone.com/NWbT6F

Comment: Thank you soul. I found the answer and post it for others. +1 for your help.

Comment: @Natasha hmmm please update ur question its quiet confusing!!! anyways will upate my regex answer too

Comment: soul, if you saw the **php floatval** link that I've mentioned in my post you could exactly saw what I wanted. :)

Comment: @Natasha the answer is exactly for php floatval!! forget it!! anyways u got a solution for it!!

Answer (score 0):

`Float#parseFloat` parse String to float.  But if string contain word character then it will throw `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: I don't need an exception. I need the Number part of the String. Thanks.

Comment: then you should extract the number then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I have given a link to learn regarding converting float value from string which are as
http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/ConvertStringToFloat.shtml
I hope this one is very helpful for you